# Xamarin forms, I have a global int that I try to save in my app, but when I restart it, the int resets

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On my cspage I create a global string:

```
public static int theNumber;
```

When I use it within a clickfunction and push it to another page my code looks like this:

```
App.theNumber = 1;    
Application.Current.Properties ["saveOurNumber"] = App.theNumber;    
Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync ();
```

Everytime I restart the app, the number starts at 0 again. Anyone know why?

Comment: Forms, crossplatform.

Comment: Does it exhibit this behavior on iOS, Android, or both?  And are you correctly initializing the value from Application.Current.Properties on startup?

Comment: Yes, same result from both. 
When I start up I only have the int (that i have stored in the app.curr.properties) in my public class App : Application.

Like this:
public class App : Application
 {

public static int theNumber;

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application starts, you have to explicitly load any saved values; it doesn't just happen magically - the [Application Lifecycle](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/app-lifecycle/#Properties_Dictionary) docs discuss this

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("saveOurNumber"))
{
    App.theNumber = (int) Application.Current.Properties ["saveOurNumber"];
}
```

Comment: "the "as" operator cannot be used with a non-nullable value type int"